# Create a TXT record in AWS by using the aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli, amazon-route53

When I execute this:

`aws route53 list-hosted-zones`

I have the following response:

```
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/Z209RXXXXXXE2L",
            "Name": "ultrasist.net.",
            "CallerReference": "ECXXXX62-EXXA-8XX9-8XX5-8E52XXXXXX81",
            "Config": {
                "Comment": "Corporate zone",
                "PrivateZone": false
            },
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 46
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I am pretty sure that I have the domain "ultrasist.net". Now, if I do this:

```
aws \
lightsail \
create-domain-entry \
--region 'us-east-1' \
--domain-name 'ultrasist.net' \
--domain-entry '{"name":"_test-txt.ultrasist.net","target":"\"xyz\"", "isAlias":false,"type":"TXT"}'
```

I got this response:

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the CreateDomainEntry operation: The Domain does not exist: ultrasist.net
```

However, as you can see, the domain DOES exist. So, my question is pretty obvious: Why Do I get this message if the domain of course is there?

Comment: Not sure if the `dot` in the domain is important or not. Did you try with it?

Comment: @Marcin The example at https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lightsail/create-domain-entry.html does not show a trailing dot in the domain name...

Comment: I tested it with the 'dot' and it didn't work either...